# Advanced Array Merge using a pattern

Tags: php, arrays

I need some help to merge 2 arrays, but with a specific pattern as demonstrated below. Any help in the logic would be greatly appreciated.

Case: I have 2 arrays

```
$arr1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
$arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I want to merge these 2 into a 3rd (new) array, but using the following pattern:
** letter, letter, number, number, letter, letter, letter, number, number **

So it's 2 letters, 2 numbers, 3 letters, 2 numbers (and then repeat). So for example if I applied this logic to the example above, we'd get

```
$arr3 = ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 'c', 'd', 'e', 3, 4, 'f', 'g', 5, 6, 'h', 'i', 'j', 7, 8
```

I was hoping someone could help me with the logic/general direction of achieving this.

FYI, The code I have so far, only deals with merging 2 arrays with alternating values:

```
//Empty array to hold new objects
$newArray = array();

foreach ($arr1 as $a1) {
    if (count($arr1)==0) {
        break;
    }
    array_push($newArray, array_pop($arr1));
    if (count($arr2)!=0) {
        array_push($newArray, array_pop($arr2));
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I seem to have offended some users with my request. I have modified the question to ask for general direction, and help with the array logic. Thanks again for your responses.

Comment: *I will be doing it in PHP, but feel free to post in any language* - Thats not how this works, you need to come with a specific problem for help, either way in c# you would just use a single for loop and take two entries from both lists per iteration

Comment: Thanks for the note although I don't understand the down vote. I'm opening this up because I personally write in JavaScript, PHP and C# hence the comment. No need to be elitist and vote me down because I didn't ask for help specifically in language A or B. Programming is about problems and solutions more so than syntax.

Comment: I've provided you the logic so I don't know how I'm being elitist here. The way you have worded your question is as a request and not as a question. If its code you want then here it is in smalltalk `arr1 doWithIndex:[:a :i | newArr add: a. arr2 size <= i ifTrue:[newArr add: (arr2 at: i)]].`

Comment: This is a nice question, only that it was not formatted like what the format usually is here. That's probably the only reason for down-votes coming in.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it fits, but i would do is cut `$arr1` by 2 then 3, then `$arr2` just normally cut by two then just merge them normally. Like this:

```
$arr1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'];
$arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
$i = 0;
$temp1 = array();
while(count($arr1) > 0) {
    // cut two then three
    $num = ($i & 1) ? 3 : 2; 
    $temp1[] = array_splice($arr1, 0, $num);
    $i++;
}

$temp2 = array_chunk($arr2, 2); // cut by twos
$arr3 = array();
foreach($temp1 as $key => $val) {
    // merge and merge
    $arr3 = array_merge($arr3, array_merge($val, $temp2[$key]));
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, nice way to use `array_chunk()`, hadn't thought about it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do sound like a programmer (and not a newbie looking for a quick fix) and you just need the logic and the direction, You can do this

**Disclaimer:** This is just to give you an idea how to go about it, of course it can be optimized and code can be reduced, but this works. This code does not perform any checks on whether the number of elements in your array are enough to satisfy your logic, you can always add them.

```
<?php
$arr1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'];
$arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

$nextSequence=2;
$counter=0;
$alphabets=array_reverse($arr1);
$numbers=array_reverse($arr2);
while($alphabet=array_pop($alphabets))
{
    if($counter==2 && $nextSequence==2)
    {
        $counter=0;
        $nextSequence=3;
        $result[]=array_pop($numbers);
        $result[]=array_pop($numbers);
    }
    elseif($counter==3 && $nextSequence==3)
    {
        $counter=0;
        $nextSequence=2;
        $result[]=array_pop($numbers);
        $result[]=array_pop($numbers);
    }
    $result[]=$alphabet;
    $counter++;
}
while($number=array_pop($numbers))
{
    $result[]=$number;
}
print_r($result);
?>
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => c
    [5] => d
    [6] => e
    [7] => 3
    [8] => 4
    [9] => f
    [10] => g
    [11] => 5
    [12] => 6
    [13] => h
    [14] => i
    [15] => j
    [16] => 7
    [17] => 8
)
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/178809)**

Comment: Thanks for the direction, it definitely helps. I am just going to create some cases for when 1 array is longer than the other. Will post results here. Thanks again :)